# Android : Create translucent edittext with image inside

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am working on an Android project in which I have a login page where I want to add Username and password fields. The design I have requires me to put them in this translucent manner and with an image inside. Any ideas what I can change for EditText to make it translucent and shape it, there are many threads to make it transparent by setting the background to null or by color and so on, but nothing like this I found.

Design :

[image]

I am using Relative layout, and those icons on right side, I have them in separate PNG files. I can directly add them inside Edittext, but I am concerned that if the username and password is long, it will start going over the image. Any strategies for that? Thank you.

Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textColor="@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_default"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"

        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

*Updated screenshot*

[image]

*Updated EditText*

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/Mail"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/Mail"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:textColorHint="@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_focused"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView" >
    </EditText>
```

layout_bg.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/traslucent_background" />
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="17dip"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the image you should be able to use `android:drawableEnd="@drawable/..."` and `android:drawableRight="@drawable/..."` which also will limit the text length.

For the background you can define a custom drawable like this:

```
<!-- background_edittext.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/traslucent_background" />

</shape>
```

Where `traslucent_color` would be defined in colors.xml, for example, like this:

```
<color name="shadow_lighter_color">#64000000</color>
```

EDIT: this would be an example of how to use `drawableEnd` / `drawableRight` with a space between text and icon:

```
    <EditText
        android:background="@drawable/background_edittext"
        android:drawablePadding="16dp"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/icon"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: This is working nicely. Can you just tell me any strategy for the 2nd problem, where username and password icon on right side dont get text written.

Comment: With this attribute (drawableEnd / Right) you do not have to worry, the text will stop right before the image :) (additionally you might add `drawablePadding` to widen the gal between text and icon)

Comment: This is working amazing, just one thing, the icon is looking too big, how can I tweak its position and size?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't. The position is fixed to the `end` or the `right` of the EditText and the size is the drawable size. You will have to generate an icon with the desired size. I usually use 24dp. In case you don't know it yet, this is an awesome utility for generating custom icons for all screen configurations: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=128&padding=0&color=9e9e9e%2C100&name=ic_emptybookingsicon3x

Comment: The icon is generated, but its clinging to the extreme end and is on top of border, adding screenshot, 2 mins please.

Comment: SCreenshot added in main post, kindly have a look.

Comment: I guess your drawable is just too big, try with a lower dp. Can you post also the code attached to that screenshot?

Comment: I have added it, kindly check the main post. The icon public dropbox link : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1994132/Mail.png

Comment: Everything looks fine except the icon, which I see has a fixed size of 46x38, am I wrong? That means you will see the icon too big on small screens and too small on large screens. The linked I posted before would generate a set of icons, 5 folders (drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, ...) that you have to save right under your app `res` folder. You can try also using the official material icon: https://design.google.com/icons/#ic_email Here you would download the _pngs_ and store them directly.

Comment: Thank you. Can I feed the Mail.png to the link you gave me and get the correct icon size? Any specifications of size while creating icons by designer? Thank you.

Comment: Sure you can, select `source: image` and upload the mail icon. Then adjust size, padding, color, etc and click on `download zip`. *WATCH OUT* when you download the zip, be sure it is a valid zip, usually I have to download it twice! Glad I can help!

Comment: Thanks. Just one last thing, should I ask the designer to create square icons? Any specific size? Thank you.

Comment: IMHO I think icons _must_ be square, specially to use them with EditTexts, Toolbar, Buttons, etc.. And a standard size is 24dp for small icons (is the size you will see in google apps for example). You might add a padding o 8-12dp also.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Define a shape drawable in your project like this:

```
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#88ff0000"/>
    <corners android:radius="32dp"/>
</shape>
```

And set it as the background for your `EditText`s. Also, add this as an attribute to your `EditText` in the XML:

```
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/any_drawable_file"
```

If you're concerned about the text overlapping with the drawable, you could add a custom `paddingRight` to your `EditText` to tackle that. It would save you the effort of inflating a custom layout.

Comment: Good to hear the latter. Do let me know what problem you faced with my code, though. Would help me get better :)